# TYPO3 PHP Update to 7.0 | the logs say "Switch statements may only contain one default clause"

Tags: php, html, error-handling, typo3

I want to update PHP from 5.6 to 7.0 but I get a 500 HTML Error and in the logs it says:

```
[Mon Oct 22 09:42:14 2018] [-:error] [pid 12784] [client 5.158.158.123] [host www.mydomain.de] PHP Fatal error:  Switch statements may only contain one default clause in /is/htdocs/wp12731216_QEO0DONMD6/www/typo3conf/ext/dam/lib/class.tx_dam_db.php on line 547
```

So I looked into the file and found as it says a dublicate default: statement:

```
if ($appendType = $TCA['tx_dam']['columns'][$field]['config']['appendType']) {
    $appended = true;
    switch($appendType) {
        case 'space':
            $rowUpdate[$field] = trim($row[$field].' '.$value);
            break;
        case 'newline':
            $rowUpdate[$field] = $row[$field].($row[$field]?"\n":'').$value;
            break;
        case 'comma':
            $rowUpdate[$field] = $row[$field].($row[$field]?', ':'').$value;
            break;
        case 'charDef':
            default:
            list($type, $appendChar) = explode(':', $appendType);
            $rowUpdate[$field] = $appendChar.$value;
            break;
        default:
            $appended = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

**So my Question is, is there a solution? Can I just edit this file and remove the last default statement? Or should I update to a different PHP Version?**

Comment: I think you should upgrade to the latest TYPO3 version first. Given that this message hints at the _dam_ extension, you are likely using TYPO3 4.x which is prehistoric.

Comment: Should have looked at your code more properly mate, 2 `default` cases are there. Remove the one after `case 'charDef':`

Comment: @JaswinderSingh I already found the solution but thank you for your time :)

Comment: @MathiasBrodala This is not possible for me, the solution I tried is updating the extension which I didn't think of first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution myself after a while...

**I had to update the Extension where the file with the error comes from.**